# Set calibre cover style on per-library basis

Tags: calibre, cover

In calibre I have some different libraries in which I store different kinds of books. Most of them don't have a "built-in" cover, so I use the cover generation function of calibre to create a cover depending on the library, e.g. :

- library 1: water, blocks, title size 100px, ...
- library 2: water, ornamental, title size 200px, ...
- library 3: silver, ornamental, title style italic, ...

but I need to manually rebuild the style each time I switch the library. I'd like to set for each library a single cover style (colors, style, font, size and so on) that I can easily apply by just clicking on `Edit metadata > Generate cover`.

Is that possible? If so, how can I do that?